# Django admin permissions

Tags: python, django, django-admin, admin

Django Admin. I removed admin's Add and Change permissions from my model, but i can not view model why?[image: Imposible to click]

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import News, Lessons, Feedback

admin.site.register(News)
admin.site.register(Lessons)

@admin.register(Feedback)
class Feedback(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        return False

    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False
```

Comment: Can you show us your `admin.py` ?

Comment: ok i will show.